# How to extract each color bar and copy them in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, diagram, libreoffice

I made a diagram to show unique columns with several colors in each, as shown in the picture.
I have hundreds of that to make and I have no idea about how to do that.

I would like to know if it's possible to extract each color bar separately and copy them under "Icons". I am not sure if the word "extract" is the correct term, but I would like to display a raw-image of that color bar.

Maybe a formula?

I am able to use Office Excel and Libreoffice Calc.
Thank you so much.
[image: image of color bars]

Comment: You're trying to take the multi-colored bar -- from each category in the stacked bar chart, "wpn1" thru "wpn10" and put that bar (as an image, chart, etc) in the cells in column K? I have some ideas how to do this - or rather how to simulate this - in Excel...

Comment: Yes correct. I still don't know how it will be used by the software we are making (need to wait how the developpement is going on that part of project) but we should be able to export it to Office Access or/and be read as a unique  multi-colored bar picture.

Comment: You'll need to create separate "charts" for each row in the data table. With some manipulation, they can be sized to fit exactly in a cell.  This is the concept around "spark lines" which MS added in a recent version of Excel, and although MS "spark lines" doesn't support this chart type, the same thing can still be accomplished with a little work. I will try to put an example together.

Comment: Look like its exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are instructions to do this manually, but this would be an ideal project to apply VBA and automate these tasks.

The idea is to create each category of stacked bar as its own individual chart, which can then be exported or copied to an image file.

This is based on the "spark lines" concept, which is small, eye-catching graphics embedded within the text of a document, as opposed to large graphics.  MS added some sparklines functionality in recent versions of Office apps, and although MS "spark lines" doesn't support stacked bar chart type, the same thing can still be accomplished with a little work.

**Step 1**: Select one row of the data and do Insert Chart, stacked bar.

[image: Select data and insert chart]

**Step 2**: Select data and Switch Rows & Columns.

[image: Switch rows and columns]

**Step 3**: Delete the gridlines, axes, chart border, etc., .

[image: Delete gridlines, axes, etc. and resize the PlotArea]

**Step 4**: Expand the Plot Area so that it covers the entire Chart Area, and format the data series to 0% gap width.

[image: Format 0% gap width]

**Step 5**: Apply your colors to each point in the series.

[image]

**Step 6**: Resize the chart to fit on a cell.

[image: Resize the chart]

**Finally** now that you have created some ChartObjects you can manipulate them. ChartObjects can be Exported as image files, or copy/paste-special as images, bmp, or enhanced metafiles, etc.

Comment: Wow really really appreciate your answer, it's exactly this. I'm at home in about few minutes and i will give it a try with my files. Can we auto-renames that ChartObjects to have the same name as B-colomn Name ?   Wpn1.bmp   Wpn2.bmp

Comment: Excellent! If it's helpful, do consider upvoting or "accepting" the answer so that others can benefit from this solution, as well, and also so that others don't try to answer it again :)

Comment: I don't understand Step 4 i am unable to do that step.

Comment: select the plot area and resize it to fit the entire chart area. then, right click on one of the series in the chart, and do "Format Data Series" which should bring up the dialog box in the 4th screenshot.

Comment: Also i am unable to use VBA and automate these tasks (who can be usefull when i'll have thousands same things to do) do i have to create a new Question ?

Comment: Yes, please create a new question, linking to this one, so that others can see what you're trying to accomplish. Also, I don't know what you mean by "Gad Width".

Comment: After the grey color i still have a Gap Width (sorry was Gap and no Gad...). If i understand right, without VBA i have to do it manually ?

Comment: ok. Before you delete the Axes, you would have to set the axis maximum value to be equal to the sum of the bar data.

Comment: Let me know when you have posted a new question. I have come up with a way to do this with VBA.