# ExcelVBA : Automating sparklines using saved template model

Tags: vba, excel, automation, ms-office, sparklines

With two of my previous question's answer i am now able to to do what i wanted to do :
[How to extract each color bar and copy them in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348571/how-to-extract-each-color-bar-and-copy-them-in-a-table)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360697/how-to-save-correctly-sparklines-models-color-width-options?lq=1

Now i am wondering how i can do to automate these tasks using ExcelVBA as suggests earlier, it would save me lots of time :
- Create a sparkline for each line (Question1)
- Using saved template model (Question2)
- Automate these tasks (Current Question)

I am really sorry i have no knowledge in ExcelVBA to do it alone.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you turn the development tab on a d record four macro as you do it manually the VBA will show up in the code editor.

Comment: See http://www.databison.com/index.php/how-to-write-a-macro-in-excel/